# Term or phrase for an easy and yet difficult task/process

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there any term or phrase to (idiomatically) describe a situation/task/process that is easy from one point of view but and at the same time difficult from another perspective.

The answer shoudl be used to fill the blank in the following sentence.

> This is a(n)---------- to deal with large number of participants.

Comment: What do you mean, easy *and* difficult? Please give a concrete example. You could even use the problem you're actually facing!

Comment: @AndrewLeach, This is in fact a Persian phrase and I'm looking for its English equivalent. Just find an option by searching in Persian Webpages. Do you have another option for this:
"A report two years ago was also critical and said that circle time was **deceptively simple**, but fraught with pitfalls for unwary teachers."

Comment: @Eilia have you looked for translations? What did that produce?

Comment: @dubious It didn't help that much. "easy and difficult" was its best suggestion!

Comment: @user66974, thanks for the suggestion, something more intense is needed to reflect that it seems easy at first, but when going further its difficulty becomes apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Being easy and difficult at the same time is an oxymoron. The phrase you are describing could be covering different concepts:

- The task is difficult but seems easy: "*The task seems deceptively easy*" or "*The task is deceptively difficult*"
- The task has easy and difficult parts: "*The task has both easy and difficult parts*"
- The task can be solved in an easy or difficult way: "*The task is as easy or difficult as you make it*"
- As you progress, the task gets more difficult: "*The task gets more difficult as you go on*"

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer.

Comment: @SlowlySwift what is it missing? The question was about an English translation to a Persian phrase. The meaning of the phrase is not clear so several ways of saying related things is provided in the hopes that one of them matches what the OP wanted.

Comment: I just mean that these are just rephrasing and not an actual word or phrase.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are looking for an expression that would be 'standard usage' in English.  There is no such expression that suits difficulty as well as simplicity.

The standard English expression for for a task that is easier than it looks is 'deceptively simple/easy'.

So under *deceptively* in the online Cambridge English Dictionary, the first entry is:

> in a way that is deceptive (= making you believe something that is not true):

- The plan seemed deceptively simple (= it seemed simple but was not).
- She writes with extraordinary clarity and makes it look deceptively easy.

Collins online dictionary gives a similar account of the phrase with this example:

- Mixed into the béchamel sauce (the same my grandmother would use to make her quiche), softened leeks can make a feather-light soufflé, a deceptively easy dish to prepare.

Which you will know is true, if you have ever had to make a bechamel sauce.

I note that the online American Merriam Webster dictionary cites 'deceptively' as the adverb, without any further explanation or related examples.  This may be because it is not a familiar usage in US English.

Moreover, neither British English dictionary cites 'deceptively hard/difficult'.  Cambridge has a related usage in its example"

> The tool is noisy to use and deceptively dangerous (= it is more dangerous than it seems).

This sounds to me odd.  I should recognise something's being said to ***look** deceptively dangerous* but not to ***be** deceptively dangerous*.  But on that analogy, it is reasonable to say that something could, *alla* Cambridge, be said to

> **be** deceptively hard/difficult

in the sense of being easier/simpler than it **seems**.

Answer (score 0):

If the task is easy because it is anyone can do it and it is hard to mess up, but hard because it takes a lot of time and/or effort then **tedious** is a good contender.

**Tedious**

> too long, slow, or dull; tiresome or monotonous: a tedious journey.

If the task is easy because it doesn't require a lot of time or effort, but hard because it is easy to mess up then you would call it **tricky**

**Tricky**

> Requiring caution or skill.

Comment: But *tedious* carries no sense of either ease or difficulty.

Comment: I think it carries the sense of difficulty due to the length. i.e walking a mile is easy, walking 25 miles isn't.

Comment: However, I would say that perhaps the asker could be more specific about what makes the task easy/hard.

Comment: I agree with @HighPerformanceMark. The OP is about something that may be easy at the thinking level but hard for doing or easy from one perspective but hard from another.

Comment: The comments do clarify her answer more to show that the word she is looking for isn't tedious, but the original answer didn't reflect that and neither does the title. So I guess I answered the question she asked and not the one she meant to ask.